# Sending email on View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, email

My computer has been stolen.I havent finished my project yet and also did not back up my project files.
Yes, very bad situation.
Everybody should use clouds or vs2012 for secure projects.

i just have mvc 3.0 publish files.I have contact form on view.Is it possible to send email via View?
my Controllers and Models became .dll file so i can only reach view files(publish files).

I have to find a way to send email.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can embed some Code in the View file. But **You should not do that**. It is a bad practice mixing UI and code together.

Use a DLL Decompiling tool to see what code is in your DLL files and write your code again. You may consider [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) or Reflector

Make sure you rely on a Sourcecontrol /better backup  strategy this time.